# How to remove newline and carriage return char from a variable used in sed command?

Tags: shell, sed, tr, busybox

I am trying to create a shell script for android.
In this script I want to edit timestamp key in a xml file
but the timestamp variable always leaves a newline trail.

I am using *sed* and *tr* commands from busybox. **":"** is the delimiter
I have tried *\r,\n* in *tr* but of no use.

**My script code:**

```
current_time=$(date +%s | busybox tr -d '\r\n')
busybox sed -i "s:name=\"timeStamp3\" value=\"[0-9]*\":name=\"timeStamp3\" value=\"$current_time\":" ./cocos2dxprefsFile.xml
```

**Input:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <int name="classic_ufg_b2" value="-10" />
    <int name="timeStamp3" value="1441985760" />
    <string name="lastName">Albert</string>
    <int name="classic_ufg_s" value="262" />
</map>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <int name="classic_ufg_b2" value="-10" />
    <int name="timeStamp3" value="**currenttime**" />
    <string name="lastName">Albert</string>
    <int name="classic_ufg_s" value="262" />
</map>
```

**Current Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <int name="classic_ufg_b2" value="-10" />
    <int name="timeStamp3" value="**currenttime**
    " />
    <string name="lastName">Albert</string>
    <int name="classic_ufg_s" value="262" />
</map>
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The `$()` strips newlines by default, you don't even need the `tr` there. Try testing that with `foo=$(echo bar); echo foobar | busybox sed "s/foo/$foo/"`. Does that return `barbar`?

Comment: @ThomasDickey yes, I know. I tried this on busybox (including `busybox sh`) and the process substitution still strips trailing whitespace. It may be down to the busybox version on the OP's android, but even if the `$()` doesn't trim it, the `tr` should.

Comment: You can prove that the `tr` isn't needed: `busybox sh -c 'echo "--$(date +%s)--"'` happily outputs
`--1449159282--`, no stray newline.  I can't reproduce the reported issue, no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

I just wonder why do u use **busybox**.. i dont have this command. 
the following script works for u.. u can try it.

```
   $ cat test.sh 
current_time=$(date +%s)
cat cocos2dxprefsFile.xml | sed "/timeStamp3/{
    s/\(value=\)\"[0-9]*\"/\1\"$current_time\"/
}"


$ bash test.sh 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <int name="classic_ufg_b2" value="-10" />
    <int name="timeStamp3" value="1449157053" />
    <string name="lastName">Albert</string>
    <int name="classic_ufg_s" value="262" />
</map>
```